# TinyMCE inside Durandal widget - callback after routing transition?

Tags: tinymce, durandal

I'm trying to use TinyMCE in a widget but it fails. I think the problem is that view is still hidden when "viewAttached" is fired. It seems that TinyMCE [has a bug/feature](http://blog.mirthlab.com/2008/11/13/dynamically-adding-and-removing-tinymce-instances-to-a-page/) (read last paragraph) and can't be displayed when the target (textarea) is hidden (or inside a hidden div).

I got it working by doing the job in a setTimeout but it's crappy.

Is there a callback that I could attached to which is fired after the view is unhided (after the transition is completed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I found one solution:</strike>

Explicitly subscribe to the "isNavigating" observable of the router and add TinyMCE when "isNavigating" value becomes false.

Still : this has the effect of flickering - you see the textarea and then it is replaced by TinyMCE... but this is not a Durandal problem IMO.

**Edit 1**

Finally, I think the the best solution (for now... follow the link below for the thread on the subject) is to do a setTimeout(xyz(), 0) - I have seen a lot of people using this technique and it prevents the flickering.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/durandaljs/5NpSwMBnrew

Answer (score -1):

Durandal does have a callbacks when you're using composition - you just put a function on to your viewModel with the correct name. In your case, you would use viewAttached:

Here's the docs:
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM/

Comment: The viewAttached event has nothing to do with the view unhided. Rob Eisenberg (creator of Durandal) said that he was working on creating more events to prevent the problem I was facing (for the next version of Durandal).